# define column names as combination of a repeated string and a vector in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I want to name the columns of a matrix by using a string and a vector of length of the rows. As an example:

```
 k<-c(5:15)
 xMin = 3
 xMax = 15
 x<-c(xMin:xMax)
 M<-matrix(, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(k))
```

Ideally, I would like to name the matrix columns using a string and the vector k, where the column name of the i'th column is the same as the item at the i'th position of the vector k.

So, I would like it to look like is this:

```
      S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 S10 S11 S12 S13 S14 S15
 [1,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [2,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [3,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [4,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [5,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [6,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [7,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [8,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [9,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[10,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[11,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[12,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[13,] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

*where the string would be "S"*.
Couriously, what didn't work was:

```
N=NULL
N<- as.vector(N)
m=1
for (m in length(k))
{
N[m]<-paste0("s_",k[m])
}
N
```

=> The output was a vector full of NA's!
Although, **when I iterated 'm' by hand, it worked** (WHY is it not working in the loop?)!

Whatever, what I wanted to get, was of course:

```
> N
 [1] "s_5"  "s_6"  "s_7"  "s_8"  "s_9"  "s_10" "s_11" "s_12"
 [9] "s_13" "s_14" "s_15"
```

which i could easily use for:

```
colnames(M)<-N
```

I would of course want to use the same procedure for naming the rows.

Comment: `paste("s", seq(from = 5, to = 15), sep = "_")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this.  `paste` is vectorized.

```
k = seq(from = 5, to = 15)
paste("s", k, sep = "_")
```

or

```
paste0("s_", k)
```

However, if you are curious why the loop fails it is because you aren't actually looping over anything besides the result of `length`.  Hence the `NA` values in the other vector elements.  You need to have something to iterate over for a loop.  In this case you could use something simple like `seq(length(k))` or `seq_along`.

```
for (m in seq_along(k))
{
  N[m]<-paste0("s_",k[m])
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this help. As do not want to use a sequence with from and to, because my vector k can have various inputs, which might not be sequential. But with the iteration using seq(length(k)) I get what I need. Thanks again.

Comment: @LxndrF you can use `k` directly

Comment: Yes, thanks. I got it.
 for (m in seq(length(k)))
{
N[m]<-paste0("s_",k[m])
}  is producing the same result as
   N <- paste0("s_"k)